# Adding dynamic year to AbleCommerce (ASP) footer

Tags: ablecommerce

I am not an ASP coder at all.  Just trying to helop a friend by adding dynamic copyright date to existing AbleCommerce footer.  My current code causes no errors but also has no output:

StoreFooter.ascx

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="thisYear"></asp:Literal>
```

StoreFooter.ascx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AdminLink.Visible = AbleContext.Current.User.IsAdmin;
            MobileLinkPanel.Visible = Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice;
            MobileStoreLink.NavigateUrl = NavigationHelper.GetMobileStoreUrl("~/Default.aspx?FSIntent=false");
            int thisYearInt = LocaleHelper.LocalNow.Year;
            thisYear.Text = thisYearInt.ToString();
        }
```

Also tried setting date as `DateTime.Now.Year`.  Can anyone see what I am missing?  I also get no output if I assign a string to thisYear.Text.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Literal use Label control. Try

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="thisYear"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Added but that is not producing output.